# Extend existing iOS app with hybrid watchOS app

Tags: angular, apple-watch, hybrid, watchos

I have an existing iOS application written in Swift. I want to extend this application with watchOS app. Is it possible to write hybrid app (for example Angular.js) for watchOS in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there is no way to write non-native watchOS apps, so you cannot use Angular.js for instance when creating a watchOS extension.

You can only write watchOS apps using Objective-C or Swift, so even if you have a "hybrid" iOS app written using Cordova for instance, you'll need to manually add a watchOS target to your Cordova project and write the watchOS code in Objective-C or Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can expand your question to explain what you mean by 'hybrid'.

For iOS and watchOS, you will need another target to support the watchOS app (assuming you are using Swift in Xcode.)  Unfortunately, there is no way I know of to have shared iOS and watchOS code.  If you start to look in to developing a watchOS app, you will see that the coding method is different (mostly in the user interface design) for the watchOS app, and needs to be done on its own.

Comment: I used wrong word. What I mean is 'native' like for example React Native or other similar technology/framework (I heard that you can do in Angular things that you can do in React Native). But never mind, David gave an answer that I need.